# My App not showing in store

Tags: 8.1, store

My app's name is Suggest aMovie. I uploaded it two days ago and it seen publishing in dev center. 
I see it here : http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=Suggest+aMovie

But if click it, this page is open "We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found".

What is the problem?

Comment: Which market(s) did you publish to, as it appears [in the UK store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/suggestamovie/9nblgggzhm6c)

Comment: And the [US store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/suggestamovie/9nblgggzhm6c)

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through the entire certification process - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt148554.aspx - and had confirmation from Microsoft that it is being uploaded?

Also:

> Note that it will take a bit more time before your app's listing will start to appear in search results

so it may take a couple of days, maybe.